# Почему браузер отключает display: fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#sendApp').click(function () {
        var mail=$('.mail').val(), ms=$('.ms').val();
        if (!mail.match(/^[-._a-z0-9]+@(?:[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/)) {
            alert('Введите корректный email');
            return false;
        }
        else if(ms.length<5){
            alert('Длинна текста должна быть более 5 символов');
            return false;
        }       
        else {
            $.post(
                "/send_t.php",  {
                    ms:ms,
                    mail:mail,
                    name:$('.name').val()                 
                }, res
            );
        }
    });
function  res(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data==='+'){
        $('body').append('<div class="modal_accept"></div>')
    }
    else  alert("Что-то пошло не так")
}

});
```

Этот код при отправке добавляет в DOM div с классом modal_accept,

стили:

```
.modal_accept {
    display: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Но браузер почему то не дает работать стилю `display:fixed` по какой причине это может быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за display: fixed? я чего-то не знаю?

Answer (score 6):

Такого значения нет,это свойство position

Comment: О боже, спасибо, очень глупая ошибка. В голове каша